# How to get all external functions used in node js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given a node js package, I can find packages it is dependant on.
For each of the dependencies, how can I get the exports that current package uses ?

Example: In a javascript file, I have following lines of code

```
var async = require('async');
......
async.mapSeries(files, function (entry, done) {
......
```

I want to be able to extract out that this js uses mapSeries function from async

Comment: Grep? Wrap everything in the module with something that logs usages?

Comment: I want to do this statically.

Comment: Grep? The problem is that if you do it statically you run the risk of missing usages, because `async.mapSeries` isn't the only way you can call `mapSeries`. In order to do this job completely you basically need to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could relatively easily do it with `esprima`, for example, but like @DaveNewton said you might miss some, due to the very dynamic nature of JS, and the fact that `exports` can be modified many different ways.

Not only will you have to "run the code" for complete, bullet-proof list, you would also have to run it with 100% coverage. Not really something worth doing, probably.

Comment: Can you please help with how I should use Esprima to do this ? I tried using scripted/server/jsdepend/reference-finder, findReferences function. This only gives me the requires and depends information. It does not tell me where-ever a function is invoked on an external dependency.

Comment: Basically you would need to parse the file, traverse the AST, and find any use assignment to what is module.exports. Not a very short piece of code, but not very complicated.